# How to build Qt-project in MSVC?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2019, qt6

I'm trying build Qt project in MSVC 2019.
I installed Qt VS Tools v.2.10.1 (rev. 2), opened my Qt-project in MSVC through Qt VS Tools. But when I try to build it I keep getting the same error:
"E2422  defaulted default constructor cannot be constexpr because the corresponding implicitly declared default constructor would not be constexpr" in Qt-library file QtCore\qrunnable.h:

```cpp
// Copyright (C) 2016 The Qt Company Ltd.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: LicenseRef-Qt-Commercial OR LGPL-3.0-only OR GPL-2.0-only OR GPL-3.0-only

#ifndef QRUNNABLE_H
#define QRUNNABLE_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>
#include <functional>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Q_CORE_EXPORT QRunnable
{
    bool m_autoDelete = true;

    Q_DISABLE_COPY(QRunnable)
public:
    virtual void run() = 0;

    constexpr QRunnable() noexcept = default;  //<- error message points here
    virtual ~QRunnable();
    static QRunnable *create(std::function<void()> functionToRun);

    bool autoDelete() const { return m_autoDelete; }
    void setAutoDelete(bool autoDelete) { m_autoDelete = autoDelete; }
};

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif
```

In VC-project settings everything seems to be well (additional libraries and directories).
Can anyone tell me some hint how can I fix that?
Thanks a lot in advance!

I tried different Qt versions for MSVC 2019
[image]:

```
5.15.2_msvc2019_64,
6.2.4_msvc2019_64,
6.3.2_msvc2019_64,
6.4.2_msvc2019_64,
```

but error is still here.

Comment: @drescherjm I added code that causes error, but that file is not my - it is part of Qt-library.

Comment: @drescherjm Sorry, didn't know that.

Comment: At work as a medical imaging researcher I use Qt5 and Visual Studio Community 2019 but I use CMake and don't use the VS addon at all. I have used CMake and Qt with Visual Studio since 2008. I can't help with Qt6 so someone else will have to address that. I also almost always build Qt from source so I don't use the online installer either.